# With highcharts, is it possible to adapt tooltip text with column color ?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I would like to know it is possible to adapt tooltip text with column color ?

For example, if my column is blue, so my tooltip title will be "Blue Title" and if it's orange, then the tooltip title will be "Orange Title".

Is that possible ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, you can use tooltip formatter, get color from series and return a span with custom style containing color value from series.

```
const options = {
  chart: { type: 'column' },
  series: [...Array(5)].map(() => ({ data: [...Array(3)].map(Math.random) })),
  tooltip: {
    formatter () {
        return `<span style="color: ${this.series.color}">
        My new tooltip
            x: ${this.x} y: ${this.y}
      </span>`
    }
  }
}

const chart = Highcharts.chart('container', options)
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4p12sf2k/

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found a solution by myself, just a little mistake I've made.

Here is my solution :

```
tooltip: {
            formatter: function () {

                    if (this.color == "#d8662c") {
                        return '<b>Title 1</b>';
                    } else if (this.color == "#009dc1") {
                        return '<b>Title 2</b>';
                    } else {
                        return return '<b>Title 3</b>';
                    }

                }
        }
```